# Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating my BaseActivity to call into another activities to call drawer and toolbar. The application opens in Above API 21. but gives error in kitkat and below.

**BaseActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer, null);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) drawer.findViewById(R.id.contentFrame);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) drawer.findViewById(R.id.drawerlinearlayout);
    listItems = (RecyclerView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.drawerListItem);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    listItems.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
}
```

It gives me error on the getLayoutInflater.inflate() method.

**drawer.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <include android:id="@+id/app_bar"
             layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/drawerlinearlayout">


    <include layout="@layout/drawerheaderimage"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/drawerListItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/drawerheaderimage">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and below is my toolbar
**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                               android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                               android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                     app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And I am using 23.2 support library..
I am doing something wrong? Plz help..And thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your complete xml layout? if so then it should be like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                               android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                               android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                               app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

Comment: while pasting the code by mistakely it removed. i edited my code.